# Minecraft LAN not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

My brother and I have used the 'Open to LAN' button before and it worked well, but I got a new computer and now it doesn't work at all.

When I host the game on my Windows 10 computer, my game won't pop up in the server list like it should, but when my brother hosts it on his windows 7 computer, his game appears in my server list.

However when I try and connect to his LAN world, it says "Java.net.connectException:Connection timed out:no further information"

How can I get LAN to work?

Answer (score -2):

Simple fix, the computer that is hosting has to have their firewall disabled. I would disconnect my router from the internet before i did this though, and enable the firewall before connecting the router back